# How to open the root folder with UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I want to show **most** root folder with UIDocumentPickerViewController on presentation.

UIDocumentPickerViewController has directoryURL feature. But I can't access the URL i want to access.
Example usage `documentPickerController.directoryURL = url`

This is where I want it to start from

[image: 1]

1- Tried `documentPickerController.directoryURL = url` but couldn't find the url i want to access.

2-  Also this one didn't work for me.

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL { // returns your application folder
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

let path = getDocumentsDirectory().absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "shareddocuments://")
let url = URL(string: path)!

UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

Comment: You can get an idea on how to do that from the oficial documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories

Comment: #Razvan, your comment is not helping at all, as it does not answer the question and the Apple URL you indicate unfortunately don't provide any pointer on how to access the root folder. I tried to use the specific directories available from iOS 16 (such as .userDirectory, .homeDirectory), but they are not displaying the root folder.